# Why does TreeStore.sync() not write to database?

Tags: php, extjs4, shopware

I've been assigned a task to extent and modify a Shopware plugin. The original author isn't in the company anymore. Before that I've never dealt with Shopware and ExtJs.
So I spend the last couple of days getting myself into it and I think I understood the principles and paradigm so far.

The only thing I'm having trouble with right now is the following issue:

I've got an `Ext.tree.Panel` which I want to save into a database using Ajax. The node is being added to the tree, I can see it appearing in the GUI. But after calling `optionsTree.getStore().sync()` there is nothing arriving in the database. The `createProductOptionAction()` in the PHP controller isn't called, but I can't figure out why. There is no error message in Browser console log, no error message in the Shopware log files. Nothing. Everything seems to work fine. But the data isn't being stored.

The original plugin had an `Ext.grid.Panel` to store and display data. And this works fine. But after changing to `Ext.tree.Panel` and modifying the code, it doesn't work anymore. From my point of view it should work tho. But it doesn't and I can't see my mistake(s).

Any help is really appreciated, I'm still a bloody beginner with ExtJs. :)

Here is what I've got so far:

**app.js**

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager', {

    extend:'Enlight.app.SubApplication',
    name:'Shopware.apps.CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager',

    bulkLoad: true,
    loadPath:'{url controller="CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager" action="load"}',

    controllers:['ProductConfigurator'],
    stores:['ProductOptionsList'],
    models:['ProductOption'],
    views: ['ProductOptions', 'Window' ],

    launch: function() {
        var me = this,
            mainController = me.getController('ProductConfigurator');
        return mainController.mainWindow;
    }
});
```

**controller/controller.js**

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager.controller.ProductConfigurator', {

    extend:'Ext.app.Controller',

    refs: [
        { ref: 'productOptionsTree', selector: 'product-configurator-settings-window product-options-tree' }
    ],

    init:function () {
        var me = this;

        me.mainWindow = me.createMainWindow();
        me.addControls();
        me.callParent(arguments);

        return me.mainWindow;
    },

    addControls: function() {
        var me = this;

        me.control({
            'product-configurator-settings-window product-options-tree': {
                addProductOption: me.onAddProductOption
            }
        });
    },

    createMainWindow: function() {
        var me = this,
            window = me.getView('Window').create({
                treeStore: Ext.create('Shopware.apps.CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager.store.ProductOptionsList').load()
            }).show();

        return window;
    },

    onAddProductOption: function() {
        var me = this,
            optionsTree = me.getProductOptionsTree(),
            parentNode = optionsTree.getRootNode(),
            nodeCount = parentNode.childNodes.length + 1,
            productOption = Ext.create('Shopware.apps.CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager.model.ProductOption', {
                parent: 0,
                type: 0,
                title: Ext.String.format('{s name="group/default_name"}New Group [0]{/s}', optionsTree.getRootNode().childNodes.length + 1),
                active: true,
                leaf: false
            });
        productOption.setDirty();
        parentNode.appendChild(productOption);
        optionsTree.getStore().sync(); // Nothing arrives at DB
        optionsTree.expandAll();
    },

    // ...
```

**view/window.js**

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager.view.Window', {

    extend:'Enlight.app.Window',

    cls:Ext.baseCSSPrefix + 'product-configurator-settings-window',
    alias:'widget.product-configurator-settings-window',

    border:false,
    autoShow:true,
    maximizable:true,
    minimizable:true,

    layout: {
        type: 'hbox',
        align: 'stretch'
    },

    width: 700,
    height: 400,

    initComponent:function () {
        var me = this;
        me.createItems();
        me.title = '{s name=window/title}Configurator Settings{/s}';
        me.callParent(arguments);
    },

    createItems: function() {
        var me = this;

        me.items = [
            me.createProductOptionsTree()
        ];
    },

    createProductOptionsTree: function() {
        var me = this;
        return Ext.create('Shopware.apps.CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager.view.ProductOptions', {
            store: me.treeStore,
            width: '20%',
            flex: 1
        });
    }
});
```

**store/product_options_list.js**

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager.store.ProductOptionsList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    pageSize: 30,
    autoLoad: false,
    remoteSort: true,
    remoteFilter: true,
    model : 'Shopware.apps.CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager.model.ProductOption',
    proxy:{
        type:'ajax',
        url:'{url controller="CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager" action="getProductOptionsList"}',
        reader:{
            type:'json',
            root:'data',
            totalProperty:'total'
        }
    }
});
```

**model/product_option.js**

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager.model.ProductOption', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [
        { name : 'id', type : 'int', useNull: true },
        { name : 'parent', type : 'int' },
        { name : 'title', type : 'string' },
        { name : 'active', type: 'boolean' },
        { name : 'type', type : 'int' }
    ],
    idProperty : 'id',
    proxy : {
        type : 'ajax',
        api: {
            create: '{url controller="CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager" action="createProductOption"}',
            update: '{url controller="CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager" action="updateProductOption"}',
            destroy: '{url controller="CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager" action="deleteProductOption"}'
        },
        reader : {
            type : 'json',
            root : 'data',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        }
    }
});
```

**php/controller.php**

```
<?php
use Shopware\CustomModels\CCB\ProductOption;

class Shopware_Controllers_Backend_CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager extends Shopware_Controllers_Backend_ExtJs
{

    public function createProductOptionAction()
    {
        // Never being called
        file_put_contents('~/test.log', "createProductOptionAction\n", FILE_APPEND);
        $this->View()->assign(
            $this->saveProductOption($this->Request()->getParams())
        );
    }

    public function getProductOptionsListAction()
    {
        // Works fine
        file_put_contents('~/test.log', "getProductOptionsListAction\n", FILE_APPEND);
        // ...
    }

    // ...
```

**EDIT 1**

I tried adding a writer for both, the store and the model, as suggested by Saki. But unfortunately it still doesn't work. The `createProductOptionAction()` in the PHP controller is never being called.

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager.model.ProductOption', {
    extend : 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields : [
        { name : 'id', type : 'int', useNull: true },
        { name : 'parent', type : 'int' },
        { name : 'title', type : 'string' },
        { name : 'active', type: 'boolean' },
        { name : 'type', type : 'int' }
    ],
    idProperty : 'id',
    proxy : {
        type: 'ajax',
        api: {
            create: '{url controller="CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager" action="createProductOption"}',
            update: '{url controller="CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager" action="updateProductOption"}',
            destroy: '{url controller="CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager" action="deleteProductOption"}'
        },
        reader: {
            type : 'json',
            root : 'data',
            totalProperty: 'total'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

What I'm wondering tho, the original plugin had no writer implemented. But when adding an entry it immediately appeared in the database.

**EDIT 2**

I added several listeners to the `store.ProductOptionsList`:

```
Ext.define('Shopware.apps.CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager.store.ProductOptionsList', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    pageSize: 30,
    autoLoad: false,
    remoteSort: true,
    remoteFilter: true,
    model : 'Shopware.apps.CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager.model.ProductOption',
    root: {
        text: 'Product Options',
        id: 'productOptions',
        expanded: true
    },
    proxy:{
        type: 'ajax',
        url: '{url controller="CCBConfigurablePhotoProductsManager" action="getProductOptionsList"}',
        reader: {
            type:'json',
            root:'data',
            totalProperty:'total'
        }
    },
    listeners: {
        add: function(store, records, index, eOpts) {
            console.log("**** Add fired");
            console.log(records);
        },
        append: function(store, node, index, eOpts) {
            console.log("**** Append fired");
            console.log(node);
        },
        beforesync: function(operations) {
            console.log("**** Beforesync fired");
            console.log(operations);
        }
    }
});
```

All these Events are getting fired. The `beforesync` event shows

```
**** Beforesync fired
Object {create: Array[1]}
  create: Array[1]
  ...
```

But still, the API requests of the `model.ProductOption` are not getting fired. It should work. Shouldn't it? Maybe this is a bug in ExtJS 4.1? Or something with Shopware + ExtJS?

**EDIT 3**

Ok, this is really getting weird.

I added a "write"-Listener to the `TreeStore`.

```
    write: function(store, operation, opts){
        console.log("**** Write fired");
        console.log(operation);
        Ext.each(operation.records, function(record){
            console.log("**** ...");
            if (record.dirty) {
                console.log("**** Commiting dirty record");
                record.commit();
            }
        });
    }
```

After adding a Node and calling `.getStore().sync()`, the `write`-event IS fired, he iterates `operation.records`, finds one record (the one I just added)... but it isn't `dirty`, even though I do `productOption.setDirty()` before adding it to the Tree?!

Thanks alot for your time! :)

Comment: On monday I have to do the same thing at work. I hope I will get it working. I'll share my experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little note on your code:
There is an error in the `beforesync` event: the function must return `true`, else `sync()` will not get fired.

I don't think this is the only problem. Since ExtJs is usually extensive code, I cannot tell you what is the reason of your problem. All I can give, is a simple working example with some explanations.

I'm following the recommended MVC layout, i.e. one file for each class. Here is the complete code:

```
Ext.define('Sandbox.Application', {
    name: 'Sandbox',
    extend: 'Ext.app.Application',
    controllers: [
        'Sandbox.controller.Trees'
    ]
});
Ext.define('Sandbox.controller.Trees', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    requires: ['Ext.tree.*', 'Ext.data.*', 'Ext.grid.*'],
    models: ['TreeTest'],
    stores: ['TreeTest'],
    views: ['TreeGrid'],
    init: function(){
        this.control({
            'treegrid toolbar button#addchild': {click: this.onAddChild},
            'treegrid toolbar button#removenode': {click: this.onRemoveNode}
        })
    },
    onAddChild: function(el){
        var grid = el.up('treepanel'),
        sel = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0],
        store = grid.getStore();
        store.suspendAutoSync()
        var child = sel.appendChild({task: '', user: '', leaf: true});
        sel.set('leaf', false)
        sel.expand()
        grid.getView().editingPlugin.startEdit(child);
        store.resumeAutoSync();
    },
    onRemoveNode: function(el){
        var grid = el.up('treepanel'),
        sel = grid.getSelectionModel().getSelection()[0];
        sel.remove()
    }
});
Ext.define('Sandbox.model.TreeTest', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeModel',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id',  type: 'int'},
        {name: 'task',  type: 'string'},
        {name: 'user', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'index', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'parentId', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'leaf', type: 'boolean', persist: false}
    ]
});
Ext.define('Sandbox.store.TreeTest', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.TreeStore',
    model: 'Sandbox.model.TreeTest',
    proxy: {
        type: 'ajax',
        url: 'resources/treedata.php',
        api: {
            create: 'resources/treedata.php?action=create',
            read: undefined,
            update: 'resources/treedata.php?action=update',
            destroy: 'resources/treedata.php?action=destroy'
        }
    },
    autoSync: true,
    autoLoad: false,
    root: {id: 1, text: "Root Node", expanded: false}
});
Ext.define('Sandbox.view.TreeGrid', {
    extend: 'Ext.tree.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.treegrid',
    store: 'TreeTest',
    columns: [{
        xtype: 'treecolumn',
        text: 'Task',
        flex: 2,
        sortable: true,
        dataIndex: 'task',
        editor: {xtype: 'textfield', allowBlank: false}
    },{
        dataIndex: 'id',
        align: 'right',
        text: 'Id'
    }, {
        dataIndex: 'user',
        flex: 1,
        text: 'Utilisateur',
        editor: {xtype: 'textfield', allowBlank: false}
    }],
    plugins: [{
        ptype: 'rowediting',
        clicksToMoveEditor: 1,
        autoCancel: false
    }],
    viewConfig: {
        plugins: [{
            ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop',
            containerScroll: true
        }]
    },
    tbar:[
        {xtype: 'button', text: 'Add Child', itemId: 'addchild'},
        {xtype: 'button', text: 'Remove', itemId: 'removenode'}
    ]
});
```

I didn't elaborate the server side code. I just copied the [Kitchensink example code](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/extjs-build/examples/build/KitchenSink/ext-theme-neptune/resources/data/tree/treegrid.json?_dc=1423577835047&sort=%5B%7B%22property%22%3A%22leaf%22%2C%22direction%22%3A%22ASC%22%7D%5D&node=root). To get to work a create, update or delete request, it has to return the modified rows along with `success: true`.

Explanations:

- I needed to launch `sencha app build` after adding the required classes in order to display everything correctly
- file `model/TreeTest.js` : the field `index` is required if we want a reorder to be saved back to the server. If it is ommitted, only rows with edited fields are saved back. It was necessary to add `persist: false` for the `leaf` field, because this data is not needed on the server.
- file `store/TreeTest.js` :

  - `autoSync: true` worked out of the box, with the restriction mentionned on reordering.
  - the tree autoLoads when the root node is `expanded: true` or if `autoLoad: true`. If we don't want to autoLoad, `autoLoad` and `expanded` must be both false.
  - root is required for a good working store. If it is missing, we must load the store manually, even if `autoLoad: true`.
  - It was necessary to add the `api` configuration. Without it, it was not possible to tell appart an update, create and delete request.
- file `view/TreeGrid.js` :

  - a column with `xtype: 'treecolumn'` is required.
  - The removal of a row is simple and syncs the store automatically. The server side is responsible for deleting children if there are.
  - The creation of a new row is trickier, because the store is `sync()`'d as soon as `appendChild()` is called (`suspendAutoSync()` is used to avoid to write the new child before it is edited). Also, the grid gets only updated, if we control the `leaf` property manually (`.set('leaf', false)`). I expect ExtJs to correctly manage the `leaf` property and consider this as a bug.

Comment: Man, thanks alot! You saved my sanity! I'm so grateful for this clear working example and your explanations! The best I've seen so far! :) There are some differences I needed to add / change for Shopware, but finally it is "alive" now! :)

Comment: You're welcome. I needed a working example as proof of concept myself. :)

Comment: I still run into some issues I do not understand. May I can ask you for some help again? All nodes added do not get their `id` property updated after `sync`. So their `id` remains `0` or `null`. An idea?

Comment: The create call must return { success : true, data : [ the created records ] }. The returned record replaces the record in the store. The id the server sends back becomes the new id. This also allows you to set other fields to their default value on the server side.

Comment: The same thing is true for updates : the server has to return the modified records after the update request.

Comment: Thanks. The server does already return the desired data. But it does not get processed somehow. After creating a Node, I get the follow Ajax result delivered from the server `{"success":true,"data":{"id":41,"parentId":0,"title":"New Group 2","active":true,"type":0}}` ... But the node does not get updated.

Comment: I don't know if there is something special with treestores. I didn't yet implement this part.

Comment: Ok, got it. :) You need to give the `TreeStore.Proxy.reader` a `root` property. In my case `root: 'data'`.

Comment: Thanks, so I don't need to find it myself.

Answer (score 0):

The proxy used by the store must have a [writer](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/ext/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Proxy-cfg-writer) configured for sync operations to talk to the server.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion. But unfortunately it doesn't work. Please see the edit in the opening post.

Comment: It there any server request - I mean when you watch Network tab in Web Inspector, do you see any xhr transfer after a change in the tree and after sync call?

Comment: No. After creating a Node in the tree I see two "getProductOptionsList" calls, along with some "data:image/gif;base..." requests in the Network tab.
I assumed that the call of "model.ProductOption.create" will automatically trigger the assigned "create"-API request?

Comment: And other operations? Move node to other parent, edit node text? It is strange, because tree is backed by store and store sends, via proxy, changes, additions and deletions. Btw, which ext version?  Edit works for sure in ext 5+

Comment: Shopware uses ExtJs 4.1. So far I only have adding nodes implemented. No drag & drop, no renaming, etc. Just got stuck on that issue which basically keeps me from implementing other functionalities unless this one is solved. Because if we can't find a solution to that problem I have to change the way it is working. Thats how I wanted it to look like: http://jsfiddle.net/nuclearping/jxbLL53v/42/

Comment: Thats weird. When adding a  `beforesync` listener to my `Ext.data.TreeStore` and output the `operations` with `console.log(operations)` I see that he is recognizing the change `Object { create: Array[1] } create: Array[1] ...`. But still doesn't fire the API events ... :/

Comment: In the fiddle you posted, proxies are memory proxies and there are no writers configured. You cannot expect any server request for this proxy type. Proxies must be `ajax` and they must have `writers`.

Comment: The fiddle is just experimental. I made it as a proof of concept for learning and understanding ExtJS. It is not a productive representation. Also from my understanding `Proxies` do have a `default writer`. http://docs-origin.sencha.com/ext/5.1/5.1.0-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.Ajax-cfg-writer - Also when outputting my TreeStore to Browser's console I can see a writer-Property present and configured. Additionally, the original code had no explicit writer either and it was working.

Comment: I just read your Answer to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24080718/ext-4-2-using-proxy-to-save-tree ... It pretty much looks like what I'm trying to do and with a similar code. Maybe this is a bug in 4.x?